# Assigning label to each record based on multiple conditions

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, grouping, labeling

This is my `df` (data.frame)

```
Distance <- c(30, 20, 32, 20)
Speed <- c(25, 24, 17, 21)
df <-data.frame(Distance,Speed)
df
  Distance Speed
1       30    25
2       20    24
3       19    15
4       20    21
```

I need to label each row based on two conditions:

1. If the distance = 20 and
2. If the speed is greater than or equals to 18.

If condition satisfied label = "Danger"
If condition not satisfied label = "Normal"

The desired output should look like this.

```
  Distance Speed  Label
   30    25 Normal
   20    24 Danger
   19    15 Normal
   20    21 Danger
```

Any way of doing this effectively?

Comment: One way is this: `df$Label = ifelse(df$Distance == 20 & df$Speed >= 18, "Danger", "Normal")`

Comment: All 3 of the methods worked well. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an if statement with your criteria and then transform the answer to the labels.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% mutate(Label = ifelse(Distance == 20 & Speed >= 18, 'Danger', 'Normal'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this should work. You create a conditional vector using `case_when`

```
require(tidyverse)

df %>%
mutate( Label = case_when( Distance == 20 & Speed >= 18 ~ "Danger" , TRUE ~ "Normal"))
```